# "Search" doesn’t search

Tags: feature-request, bug, search, search-box

I often find that the Stack Overflow "Search…" feature fails to find pages that I know exist. So I revert to using [DuckDuckGo](http://www.DuckDuckGo.com/) or [Google](http://www.Google.com/) for `site:stackoverflow.com foo bar` searching.

Here is an example where I had posted a Question with `Vaadin` & `Flyway` in the title, and posted under my own name starting with `Basil`. Yet a search within Stack Overflow for `Basil Vaadin Flyway` shows zero results.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of two web pages, one where a Stack Overflow search reports zero results for the words "Basil Vaadin Flyway" while a second web page shows an existing Question in Stack Overflow containing those words.]

Comment: Perhaps whomever is responsible for implementing search on SO should search SO for some questions that might help them to fix it. Oh wait, ... never mind.

Comment: The way you have indicated where to look in that image is beautiful. +1

Comment: It doesn't index user names and does a poor job parsing code snippets.  Searching for "flyway vaadin" is good enough, first hit.  But sure, use the people that know how to do search.

Comment: searching for posts by a user name? You'll have to use their ID (go to the user's profile for their ID filled in the search box): [`user:642706 Vaadin Flyway`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A642706+Vaadin+Flyway)

Comment: @SamuelLiew How about making an Answer of that comment for me to accept?

Comment: If you want to search by username, good news - we can still use SEDE as an alternative.